# Prove that three points are on the same line

Tags: geometry

Let $I$ be the incenter of triangle $ABC$.Let's call the circumscribed circle of $ABC$ $w$.Let's take another circle that touches $AB,BC$ and $w$.That circle touches $w$ at P.And let's divide arc $BAC$ into two equal arcs and call the dividing point $D$.And prove that $P,I,D$ are collinear.

I did try this.

$BI\cap(w)=F$

$CI\cap(w)=Q$

And tried to prove that $\angle FBQ=\angle DPC$.

Comment: If three points are concurrent, they're the same point? Sorry I've only heard of "concurrent" for lines

Comment: Fixed the problem.

Comment: That is called collinear by the way :)

Comment: Please provide a picture. Note that there are two circles tangent to the lines $AB$, $AC$, and to the circle $(w)$, which one should we consider?